# asp.net custom error page and file without extension

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, custom-error-pages

How can i get IIS 7 to return my custom error pages for file without extension? I got it working for file with extension, but when the extension is not specified, i get the generic page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [adding a wildcard application extension](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/) that maps to the aspnet_isapi.dll.

Without that mapping, requests will never hit the aspnet dll for processing and the default IIS 404 page will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are dealing with such a situation you should handle these no extension files and then redirect to your custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7 supports extension less URLs, you can use this with combination of  Urlrewriting.net

here is very good article about achieving what you want.

http://www.vinodunny.com/blog/post/ASPNET-Extensionless-URL-ReWriting-in-IIS-7.aspx

Comment: i am actually using urlrewriter.NET and even after applying what the article says, i have no luck getting it to work