# Custom Error not working in actual website for 404

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I am trying to setup custom error for my website which works fine on local-host `mode="On"`.

But same fails on actual website.

Below is my code for web.config

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/error/Message.aspx?msg=The page you requested could not be found.">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/Default.aspx?PID=32"/>
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/error/Forbidden.aspx"/>
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/error/Error.aspx"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error/InternalError.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

I am using IIS 7.5 on my local machine and same is being used on the web server.

Do i need to change any specific setting on Production server to make it work

Error message i am still getting on live website for 404

```
Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.
Web Server at xyz.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final version with following code worked

```
...
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/error/Message.aspx?msg=The page you requested could not be found.">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/Default.aspx?PID=32"/>
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/error/Forbidden.aspx"/>
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/error/Error.aspx"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error/InternalError.aspx"/>
</customErrors>

....

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/error/Default.aspx?PID=32" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

the web.config part seems to be ok, even if I would suggest static html for default error page redirection.

How do you test this issue on remote server? 
By typing url **xyz.com/xxxxxx** where xxxxxx is page which not exist?

**If yes, so is xxxxxx without file extension?** 
And does 404 redirect works if xxxxx ends with file extension which is one of website default page? **e.g. xxxx.aspx**

Try this post
[asp.net custom error page and file without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815692/asp-net-custom-error-page-and-file-without-extension)

Comment: I just noticed that when i add `xxx/abc.aspx` then 404 works if i do it like `xxx/folder/` or `abc.com/abc/` then it doesn't work..

Comment: Hi, I think that here you can find solution: [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101110/iis7-web-server-custom-errors-works-on-local-but-not-when-published-to-product). More details in [IIS reference](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors).